# How to use a filter on a lens with a bulbous front element? (Rokinon AF 14/2.8)

Tags: filters, wide-angle, samyang

I have a wide-angle lens, but the hood does not come off. The lens is a Rokinon/Samyang AF 14mm f/2.8. Is there a way to use a filter besides using an adapter filter?

Comment: Also related: [What type of lens filter goes between the lens and body and has metal flakes in it?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/104777/15871) and [Why would I use a rear gelatin filter over a front filter?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/39345/15871)

Answer (score 0):

One option is holding the filter in front of the lens using your left hand. Use your right hand to activate the shutter.

I heard Pulitzer winner Michael S. Williamson describe the technique once. Particularly useful for graduated ND filters when running and gunning. Square filters are probably easier than round.